# artifacts at edges of spheres - incorrect lighting?

Tags: linux, opengl, nvidia, lighting

I am rendering many spheres using glutSolidSphere. There are lines at the boundary, which are not rendered in the correct color:

[image: lines at the boundary]

If I recall correctly, I did not have this problem with AMD cards, it is a new problem on nVidia.

Relevant opengl settings (not sure I got all of them, they are scattered through the code) are:

```
// set 2 lights, both having specular, ambient and diffuse components.
// and then:
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER,1);
glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE,1);
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_RESCALE_NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still get the issue if you turn off GL_LINE_SMOOTH and GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH?

What's you blending mode?  And are you drawing the spheres from furthest->closest to get correct blending (not that you can guarantee that the triangles i the spheres will be rendered in the correct order).

I'd suggest ditching the polygon smoothing if this is the problem and and using FSAA.

Comment: It is good when `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH` is off, thanks. I did not set any blending mode, is that a problem? The spheres are not ordered before rendering. What is FSAA? (Sorry, I am not very fluent in OpenGL)

Comment: Blend mode:
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

FSAA is full-scene anti-aliasing.  You can set up opengl to use a multi-sampled buffer that handles the anti-aliasing.  This avoids the problems of order-dependent blending of anti-aliased edges.